# How to change base url in Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, routes, laravel-5

Is there anyway to change base url in laravel from controller?

I have two modules in my website one is `normal browsing` and another is `subscription browsing`. What i want is , when a user comes to my website first, they get to choose what they want to browse. For example if they want to do normal browsing, then i want to redirect to normal browsing and the url should be `www.example.com/normal`  and i want to make this base url. so what ever link he click there after will be like `www.example.com/normal/somelink` . Simillarly for subscription  it will be like `www.example.com/subscription/somelink`.

If it is possible how can check in the route that he is in ***subscription browsing/ normal browsing*** ?

As of now i am adding prefix in the `route` . But sometime some url such as `login`,`user/profile` etc are becoming exception.

So how can i do so, if it possible. Any advice. ty.

**My route as of now**

```
/**
 * NORMAL BROWSING
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'activity'],'namespace' => 'Frontend'], function () {
    Route::prefix('normal')->group(function () {
      .......
     .......
    });
});

/**
 * SUBSCRIPTION BROWSING
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'activity'],'namespace' => 'Frontend'],function(){
    Route::prefix('subscription')->group(function () {  
       ........
      ........
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Little change to your code shall make it work. Assuming auth and web are middlewares

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'normal',  'middleware' => ['auth', 'web'], 'namespace' => 'Frontend'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function() {} );
    Route::get('/page2', function() {} );
});
```

This should give take your application home page to website.com/normal and page 2 should be website.com/normal/page2

You can mention other routes outside of the group.

If you want to check if a user is a normal user or a subscription user. you can create a new middleware and use that middleware in the route.

I see that you have already made two middlewares web and activity. Why are you using both the middlewares on a single group route?

Comment: Yes, I am doing like that but thinking is there way to make that URL as base URL as if permanent redirection. I am using web middle ware to check guest browsing only, activity middle ware records all user activity that can be guest, authenticated, authenticated and activated email and so on that's is why 2 middle ware in same group

Comment: What do you mean when you say permanent redirection. Are you trying to change the base url of the application to site.com/normal?

Comment: So the web and activity middlewares have nothing to do with the subscription. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that only when user click on normal browsing. And yes web middlewar doesn't have anything to do with subscription